# Using derived class for UserControl - how to eliminate blue-lining in xaml editor?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, user-controls

I'm trying to use a C# class derived from UserControl as the base class for some xaml pages' layout root, so I can share some common functionality.  I.e. the backing class is like:

```
public class BaseView : UserControl
{
    // Some virtual functions I want in common ...
}

public class MyView : BaseView
{
    // Overidden functions ...
}
```

The xaml file then references the class like:

```
<jt:BaseView x:Class="ns.MyView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:jt="clr-namespace:ns"
    ...>
</jt:BaseView>
```

This seems to work when running, but in the xaml editor, the code is all underlined with blue squiggly lines, with a fly-over message of something like "Cannot create instance of BaseView".

If I don't do this, and use UserControl in the xmal, I get errors because the partial class generated from the xaml then has the UserControl base class and not my custom base class.

How do I get the editor to know about my custom base class (i.e. get rid of the blue underlines)?

Comment: What do you have in your BaseView constructor?

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause for a design time "Cannot create instance..." sort of error is that the constructor of the element is doing something that doesn't make sense or is unavailable at design time.

Comment: Thanks!  That was it.  The base class constructor should not expect to be able to reference the App object.  Apparently it is okay for the derived class constructors to do so, so moving the common code to a base class function to be called by the derived class constructors seems to work.